# Custom composed look do not appear in "change the look"

Tags: master-page, front-end, schema

I've got:
- custom master page
- custom color palette
- custom font schema
- and made a preview file

--> deployed to farm

In the "composed look" list everything looks right. But when I go to "Change the look" it do not appear.

I've checked the links (masterpage, fonts, color...) and everything looks right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check the location of themeurl, fontschemeurl!!! It must be placed under

**/_catalogs/theme/15**

```
<Field Name="ThemeUrl">~sitecolletion/_catalogs/theme/15 .... </field>
<Field Name="FontSchemeUrl">~sitecolletion/_catalogs/theme/15 .... </field>
```

Answer (score 3):

Also you should have preview file for your custom theme. 
For example:

- mymaster.html
- mymaster.master
- mymaster.preview

Comment: I just made a copy of my .master file. Do I need to make a copy of preview and html as well and rename it to my custom masterpage?

Comment: @Batman - If you use publishing feature then you work with mymaster.html - sharepoint will update mymaster.master file. If you dont have publishing than you have only mymaster.master.

Preview file just copy and rename.

ps. if you have publishing feature you can "break" connection and just use .master version (edit mymaster.html properties in /_catalogs/masterpage, and uncheck _Associated File_ )