# Composed Look with Custom Master Page

Tags: theme, composed-looks

I am trying to make a Composed Look with a Custom Master Page.  To start with, I copied Seattle.master to Test.master; Seattle and Test are exactly the same except for the name.  I verified that I can switch the master page to Test.master.  In Composed Looks, there is an OTB item named Orange; this is the look I started with.  I created a Composed Look named Andrew.  When I copy the values of Orange exactly into Andrew, Andrew appears in Change the Look.  When I change the master page for Andrew to Test.master, Andrew does **not** appear in Change the Look.

Can anyone tell me why the Composed Look is not working with Test.master?

These are the steps to reproduce:

1. Open Browser1
2. Settings -> Site settings
3. Click “Composed looks
4. Click “new item”
   a.  Title = Andrew
   b.  Name = Andrew
   c.  Master Page URL = /sites/development/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master
   d.  Theme URL = /sites/development/_catalogs/theme/15/palette015.spcolor
   e.  Display Order = 0
5. Save the item.
6. Open Browser2
7. Settings -> Site settings
8. Click “Change the look”
9. Andrew shows up in the list
10. Go back to Browser1
11. Edit “Andrew”
    a.  Master Page URL = /sites/development/_catalogs/masterpage/Test.master
12. Save the item
13. Go back to Browser2
14. Refresh the page
15. Andrew no longer appears in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not having a .preview file for my Master Page.  I figured it out by looking at this article: [Custom composed look do not appear in "change the look"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80142/custom-composed-look-do-not-appear-in-change-the-look)

To generate a .preview file:

1. Copy Seattle.preview and name it Test.preview.
2. Upload Test.preview to the Masterpage gallery.
3. Andrew now appears in step 15 in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I follow exactly same steps as yours for testing purpose. And I can see the Composed Look. The only difference from your description here is I have published the master page.

[image]

I will check this [link](https://bniaulin.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/step-by-step-create-a-sharepoint-2013-composed-look/) that explain how to deploy the composed look, that is a more legit process. Because you would need to see the customized master page in drop-down of Change the Look.